# How to use a subquery/join with three tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

**testplan**

1. id
2. testplan_id
3. tcversion_id
4. platform_id

**executions**

```
1. id
2. build_id
3. testplan_id
4. tcversion_id
5. platform_id
6. status
7. execution_ts
8. tester_id
```

**builds**

```
1. id
2. testplan_id
3. name
4. active
```

I have three tables as shown above. 
testplan table stores all the cases
executions tables store execution related data
builds table stores builds related data

I want to retrive data from these table in such a way that it should display all rows from testplan table, for each row if any execution is there from execution's table and only the build names from builds tables.

I used following query

```
SELECT
tptcv.id,
tptcv.testplan_id,
e.tcversion_id,
tptcv.platform_id,
tptcv.creation_ts,
b.name AS Build_name,
e.status AS status,
e.execution_ts,
e.tester_id
from testplan tptcv
inner join executions e on tptcv.tcversion_id=e.tcversion_id and     tptcv.platform_id=e.platform_id and tptcv.testplan_id=e.testplan_id
inner join builds b on tptcv.testplan_id=b.testplan_id
WHERE
b.active=1 

enter code here
```

This query doesn't giving me the expected result as enter code here per the count needed compare to rows in testplan table.

I will appreciate if some help me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Could you please give me your email so that I can send you sample data and desired results. I tried to attached files/images to this post but couldn't do that since I am a new user on this forum and it didn't allowed me attached files. Thanks

Comment: You can upload photos to file share site and then paste the link here.

Comment: Please refer these links for photos of sample data of all table, query result and result I am expecting [testplan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ByX-CfgiWkV2dIN0tadmM4VWc/edit?usp=sharing)
[executions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ByX-CfgiWkQzJzTUU4VnlLZkE/edit?usp=sharing)
[builds](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ByX-CfgiWkVkVNRlB4dERIVzA/edit?usp=sharing)
[QueryResult](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ByX-CfgiWkTHZQdE9mU1JjX1E/edit?usp=sharing)
[ExpectedResults](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ByX-CfgiWkdi1vMk5aWVh1akk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `WHERE b.active = 1` and check whether you get expected answer (because build table do not have a column called `active`)

Comment: active field is there in my table, I forgot to mention in it my post